# I am unable to open Ubuntu in VMware

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

At first there were no problems but now when I reopened it again it shows me this

```
[ 2.382448] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus Host Controller not enabled!

/dev/sda3: clean, 189912/1277952 files,4863214/5110784 blocks
```

What must be done?